# Code Is Same But The Popup Menu Looks Different In Another Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, popupmenu

So I'm trying to create a popup menu when someone clicks on a more vert icon. It worked perfectly fine. But in one activity the popup menu looks weird. The text is black and ultra small for some reasons. I'm using the same code and no custom style is applied in any activities.

**Code**

```
p =  new PopupMenu(this,more);
p.inflate(R.menu.topic_menu);

more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                p.show();
            }
        });
```

Code is pretty basic like the above.

**Menu File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/report"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Report Topic" />

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/mute"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="Mute Topic" />

    </group>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Delete Topic" />
</menu>
```

But the issue,

Looks normal in three activities,

[image: normal ss]

But looks weird in this one,

[image: weird ss]

In the image, it looks like the text is hidden. But the text is actually there. If you zoom you'll see ultra small black texts in that popup menu

I don't know if the imageview code for the more_vert icon matters, but here it is,

```
                     <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/more"
                        android:layout_width="26dp"
                        android:layout_height="26dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/baseline_more_vert_white_36dp"
                         />
```

So where can be the issue? Need help :(

Comment: Is the "weird" looking activity based on a different theme?

Comment: @Traendy I haven't assigned any custom themes. But that imageview is inside CoordinatorLayout > material.appbar.AppBarLayout > material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout > RelativeLayout > then the more_vert imageview. I don't know if that can be a issue. Other than that nothing unusual in the layout file.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind fixed it.

I was just typing PopupMenu and Android Studio was autocompleting the import. So I never had any doubts about that. But I just checked the imports again and....

For normal activities the import was,

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu;
```

For not so normal activities the import was,

```
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
```

So I changed it to,

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu;
```

and everything is normal now. All that headache for this simple thing. Sorry.